# MVC 3 Route problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

ActionLink result "http://localhost:5089/Article/GetArticlesByCategory?category=ASP.NET&categoryId=2". i want to show that link type "http://localhost:5089/Blog/ASP.NET". what is wrong  route named "Article".

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

 routes.MapRoute(
                "Article",
                "Blog/{category}", // 
                new { controller = "Article", action = "GetArticlesByCategory", category = UrlParameter.Optional, categoryId = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(k.Name, "GetArticlesByCategory", "Article",
new { category = k.Name, categoryId = k.CategoryId }, null)
```

**SOLVED**

GetArticlesByCategory parameter int categoryId changed to >> string category and replaced action codes as to new parameter (string category)

Routes replaced with:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Category",
            "Blog/{category}",
            new { controller = "Article", action = "GetArticlesByCategory", category = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

ActionLink replaced with:

```
@Html.ActionLink(k.Name, "GetArticlesByCategory", "Article",
new { category = k.Name }, null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues.  First, and most important, your routes are specified in the wrong order.  The default route should be defined last.  Second, never define a route with two optional parameters.  It just causes too many problems.

Try the following for your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CategoryAndId",
    "Blog/{category}/{categoryId}", 
    new { controller = "Article", action = "GetArticlesByCategory" } 
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "CategoryOnly",
    "Blog/{category}", 
    new { controller = "Article", action = "GetArticlesByCategory",
        category = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the action in the route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Article",
                "Blog/{action}/{category}/{categoryId}", // 
                new { controller = "Article", action = "GetArticlesByCategory", category = UrlParameter.Optional, categoryId = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

I suggest you use Phil Haack's routes debug, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx.  A great way for debugging your MVC routes

Comment: What is the name of the controller and action you need to use for this route?

Comment: controller = "Article" and action = "GetArticlesByCategory"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link to show as `http://localhost:5089/Blog/ASP.NET`, you'll need to change the actionlink as such:

```
@Html.ActionLink(k.Name, "GetArticlesByCategory", "Article",
    new { category = k.Name }, new { @title = "Kategorisindeki Makaleler", @class = "selected" })
```

Since you don't want the CategoryID in the link, there is no need to put it in. the route isn't being matched by the actionlink because it expects a CategoryID parameter as well

**EDIT**

If you want the CategoryID to be read from the route, it needs to be added to the route. otherwise it will just be appended as a parameter (like in your original example).

If you change your route to:

```
"Blog/{categoryId}/{category}"
or
"Blog/{category}/{categoryId}"
```

The link will now look like `Blog/2/ASP.NET` or `Blog/ASP.NET/2` but if you want the categoryId to be read from the URL, then I don't think you have much choice

Comment: categoryId parameter of GetArticlesByCategory